# How can I check if the node is in sync (both bor and heimdall) and check the block difference for bor?

Tags: polygon-pos

I want to check if bor and heimdall are synced for my validator node, How can I do that? Also, can we determine the block difference for both bor and heimdall? Where can I check the current block details?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below commands to check that

**For Heimdall:**

curl localhost:26657/status

**In the output if the catching_up value is:**

true — the Heimdall service is syncing.

false — the Heimdall service is synced.

**For Bor**

**To check the difference between the current block and the chain tip**

bor attach .bor/data/bor.ipc

eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock

**To check whether the node is fully caught up to the chain tip**

false — the Bor service is synced.

true(i.e. If the block height values are displayed)- the Bor service is syncing.

**Note:**

For Heimdall- Always check whether the latest_block_height is incrementing if it isn't then the node is stuck.

For Bor- Always check whether the Block difference is reducing.

To check the latest block details you can use the following resources

**For Bor**

1.Staking Dashboard- https://staking.polygon.technology/

2.Polygonscan-https://polygonscan.com/

3.Vitwit Dashboard-https://bor-mainnet.vitwit.com/

**For Heimdall**

1.Staking Dashboard- https://staking.polygon.technology/

2.Vitwit Dashboard-https://heimdall-mainnet.vitwit.com/